# SharePoint - Force Mobile Menu

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I am using a SharePoint communication site, and would like to force the mobile header (The one that appears < 1024px)

I was hoping to inject some css, but it looks more dynamic than that and adds the burger button in?

[image: Button added]

Does anyone know how we can force this mobile menu in desktop view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else with this issue, it is not possible, we ended up implementing a [Side Menu Webpart](https://github.com/tom-daly/spfx-side-navigation)